# Problem in Uploading Image in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-storage, multer

i am trying to upload an image to azure blob storage, the problem m facing is the image is getting successfully uploaded  but the name of the image on azure is randomly generated by the azure itself, i want to name the image myself from the code

following is the code which i am using

```
var multer = require('multer')
var MulterAzureStorage = require('multer-azure-storage')
var upload = multer({
storage: new MulterAzureStorage({azureStorageConnectionString:
'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorageaccount;
AccountKey=mykey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net',
containerName: 'photos',
containerSecurity: 'blob',
fileName : ?//how to use this options properties
})
}  )
```

Comment: Seems like this is a question about multer, and not about Azure Storage. Azure Storage doesn't generate random blob names; looks like this is the default behavior for multer when you don't specify a filename. Perhaps look at the multer [DiskStorage](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage) documentation, which seems to cover it.

Answer (score 4):

According to the `README.md` description of [`MantaCodeDevs/multer-azure-storage`](https://github.com/MantaCodeDevs/multer-azure-storage), the `fileName` optional property must be a function which return a custom file name as the blob name stored into Azure Blob Storage.

[image]

Otherwise when `fileName` is not a function, it will use the default [`blobName`](https://github.com/MantaCodeDevs/multer-azure-storage/blob/master/index.js#L8) function below to generate a unique name to avoid naming conflicts.

```
const blobName = (file) => {
    let name = file.fieldname + '-' + uuid.v4() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    file.blobName = name
    return name
}
```

So I test it with my sample code below, it works for uploading a `1.png` file as blob into Azure Blob Storage.

```
var getFileName = function(file) {
    return '1.png'; 
    // or return file.originalname;
    // or return file.name;
}

var upload = multer({
  storage: new MulterAzureStorage({
    azureStorageConnectionString: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<your account name>;AccountKey=<your account key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net',
    containerName: 'test',
    containerSecurity: 'blob',
    fileName: getFileName
  })
});
```